# Manipulate string in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, string

I am writing a shell script for some purpose. I have a variable of the form --

```
var1 = "policy=set policy"
```

Now I need to manipulate the variable var to get the string after index `=`. That is I should have "set policy". Also I need to to this for many other variables where the value of "=" is not constant. Like

```
var2 = "bgroup = set bgroup port"
var3 = "utm = set security utm"
```

Can you give me an idea how to do it, please?

Comment: Please accept more answers. Also, be aware that you cannot have a space before or after the assignment operator in most shells.

Comment: The 'too localized' close voter needs to get out of their own shell and into the real world.  This is a question about shell programming and fully on topic for SO.

Comment: Which shell are you scripting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${var#*=}
```

removes the shortest match of `*=` from the left. Note that this is not in place: if you want to save the result, you'll have to store the result in a variable.

On a side note, this is for bash. AFAIK it also works for ksh and zsh, but not csh or tcsh.

Comment: This is valid POSIX shell code. (*csh are not POSIX shell implementations.)

Answer (score 0):

Other ways that is not dependent on what shell you have.

```
$ var1="policy=set policy"
$ echo $var1 | awk '{sub(/.[^=]*=/,"")}1'
set policy
$ echo $var1 | cut -d= -f2-
set policy
$ echo $var1 | ruby -e 'puts gets.split(/=/,2)[1]'
set policy
$ echo $var1 | sed 's/.[^=]*=//'
set policy
```